# Laravel Stapler Upload To Wrong Directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have set the Laravel public directory in `laravel/bootstrap/paths.php` to `__DIR__.'/../../public_html/laravel'` but, Laravel Stapler still uploads to `[base]/public` directory.

Does Laravel Stapler have specific config file?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/laravel-stapler/blob/master/src/config/filesystem.php) Laravel Stapler has a config file yes.

Look in your `config` folder for `filesystem.php` and change `path` there.

Comment: Yes. I've used that. But it seems not a nice solution. A believe, it'd better to configure this somewhere else.